# Replace a string containing backslash using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I want to substitute a variable SERVICE with a string $service which contains a backslash using sed. I did the following

```
sed "s/SERVICE/`printf '%q' "${service}"`/g"
```

Using this I am getting the substituted string as

```
b_a^c_b_\]Wdd[]X\[X\[W206C?2@,.\\,A@2AW!w6"|
```

where as I want

```
b_a^c_b_\]Wdd[]X\[X\[W206C?2@,.\,A@2AW!w6"|
```

Is there any other way to do it. 
PS(The string $service has many different special characters)

Comment: what is value of $service ?

Comment: How do you set the value of the service variable? Your example works fine for me (I do service="a\a", and only one backslash appears in the replaced string).

Comment: try using single quotes

Comment: The value of $service is `b_a^c_b_]Wdd[]X[X[W206C?2@,.,A@2AW!w6"|`

Comment: But then there is no backslash in your $service value!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might as well not use [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) at all but just [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) like this instead:

```
while read -r; do
    echo "${REPLY//SERVICE/$service}"
done
```